# Creating login , using mysql server 5.7.14 and workbench 6.3 and c# window form application

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to make a check (login) on the user which is entering into my application. i have made a database and table named 'mydb', 'employee' respectively. i have entered username and password into uname and pasword columns of table employee. what i want to do is that whether the username and password entered by user is valid or not? it means is it exists in table employee or not? if yes allow access and if not access denied.
for this purpose  i have written following code in my c# window form application using visual studio 2013 ultimate.

```
try
{
    string myconnection = "datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=shaban;  ";
    MySqlCommand selectcommand = new MySqlCommand(" slect * from mydb.employee where uname= "+this.username_txt.Text+" and pasword = "+this.pasword_txt.Text+"", myconn);

    MySqlDataReader myreader;
    myconn.Open();
    myreader = selectcommand.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 0;
    while (myreader.Read())
    { 
       count = count + 1; 
    }

    if (count == 1)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("username and pasword is correct"); 
    }
    else if (count > 1)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password...! Access Denied "); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(" username and pasword not existing.. Try again" ); 
    }
    myconn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{    
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);    
}
```

Comment: `slect` that's a major typo. Tell us that isn't one, otherwise your question may get closed because of it, being a "typo".

Comment: If uname and pasword are text field then you are not correctly quoting your values, but that's not a valid fix. Try to understand why and how to use a parameterized query

Comment: Read up on how to construct a query using Parameters better know as `Parameterized Queries` also read up on what `SQL Injection is` also besides posting code.. please statie what the issue is not to mention fix the poor formatting of this code..

Comment: also why are you Selecting * from the table when you are only checking Username and Password.. you should Select on the columns that you are checking not everything..

Comment: While we are at it, hash your passwords, don't save as cleartext.

Answer (score 1):

First of All there is typo in your query "slect"
Secondly you have missed single quotes in your WHERE Clause.

```
where uname= '"+this.username_txt.Text+"' and pasword = '"+this.pasword_txt.Txt+"'"'
```

Let me know if these things solve your problem. We will see next thing.

Also be specific about the error or problem you are facing.